# Get row index in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid in asp.net (vb.net) which is being populated from a Database, the first two fields are a check box and a button image.

I want that whenever the user clicks the button another form is opened to edit the content of the row. The issue is that the button is being loaded dynamically by the visual studio for each row. How can I know which row the button was selected from so that I can pass the parameters of the row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use DataGrid/DataGridView events as CellClick, CellDoubleClick, CellContentClick... and get it through e.RowIndex or e.ColumnIndex. For example,

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.CellClick

            If e.ColumnIndex = 8 Then 'only executed for cells at column 8

                Dim newForm As New MyNewForm(e.RowIndex)

                newForm.Show()

            End If

        End Sub
```

and, on MyNewForm, add Sub New to retrieve row index,

```
Public Class MyNewForm

    Private intRowIndex As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal rowIndex As Integer)

        intRowIndex = rowIndex

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub
...
```